# Readout XML-file from local VS2013 project (but not from harddrive-directory)

Tags: c#, local, xml

I have to readout an XML-file (with already existing content) from my local Visual Studio 2013 project structure, but not from harddrive-directory (as mentioned in the most tutorials/ guides, I've read in the last 2 hours...). After the readout process, I have to search for some tag-names in it.

I have to do this way, because the requirement is, that the specified local XML-file shouldn't appear after the build process in output directory...

So how can I do that?

Comment: See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292). I'd add it as an answer with an example, by SO keeps giving me `an error occured` when I try and post it.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to have finally gone through.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292).

In short:

```
// using System.Reflection, System.IO, System.Xml

var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var textStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream('resoucename.xml');
var xmlReader = new XmlReader(textStream);
...
```

To add a resource, go to it's properties and change the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` and `Copy to output directory` to `Never`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to my xml-file :((